# converting arbitrary date time format to panda timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a column in a dataframe to timeseries, the values in the column are strings and they are in the following form:
12/10/202110:42:05.397
which means 12-10-2021 at 10:42:05 and 397 milliseconds. This is the format that Labview is saving the data into a file.
I'm trying to use the following command, but I can't figure out how to define the format for my case:
pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime, format=???)
Note that there is no space between year 2021 and hour 10

Comment: I miss the old day when I built my projects with labview. `pd.to_datetime('12/10/202110:42:05.397', format='%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S.%f')`. You may see this for all the format codes. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @RaymondKwok. I just saw your comment. I can remove my answer if you want.

Comment: That's all fine, and actually yours is closer to what Mohsen asked :) Thank you Corralien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(df)

# Output
                 DateTime                      dt
0  12/10/202110:42:05.397 2021-10-12 10:42:05.397
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['12/10/202110:42:05.397']})
```

As suggested by @RaymondKwok, use the documentation:

[`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)